# How to speed up Windows Messenger

Tags: windows-7, speed, windows-live-messenger

Windows Live Messenger seems extremely slow on my Windows 7 machine. Double click on the icon and it is 10 seconds before the main screen is shown - probably because it is loading all sorts of adverts and social feeds (all facebook etc social feeds are switched off)

Is there any way I can speed it up by stopping it loading all the adverts etc?

I have had several times when a chat window is completely blank as well!

Answer (score 1):

Use [A-Patch](http://apatch.org/) and ease your pain.